# ValueError: shape mismatch: with same shape

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I got a basic error with strange output that I do not understand verywell:

**step to reproduce**

```
arr1 = np.zeros([6,10,50])
arr2 = np.zeros([6,10])
arr1[:, :, range(25,26,1)] = [arr2]
```

That generate this error:

`ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (1,6,10) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,6,10)`

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `arr2 = np.zeros([6,10,1])` solves you problem.

Comment: Why the strange `range(25, 26, 1)` notation? Why not just `25:26`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra dimension to `arr2`:

```
arr1[:, :, range(25,26,1)] = arr2.reshape(arr2.shape + (1,))
```

Easier notation for `range` as used here:

```
arr1[:, :, 25:26)] = arr2.reshape(arr2.shape + (1,))
```

(and `slice(25,26,1)`, or `slice(25,26)`, could also work; just to add to the options and possible confusion.)

Or insert an extra axis at the end of `arr2`:

```
arr1[..., 25:26] = arr2[..., np.newaxis]
```

(where `...` means "as many dimensions as possible"). You can also use `None` instead of `np.newaxis`; the latter is probably more explicit, but anyone knowing NumPy will recognise `None` as inserting an extra dimension (axis).

Of course, you could also set `arr2` to be 3-dimensional from the start:

```
arr2 = np.zeros([6,10,1])
```

---

Note that broadcasting *does* work when used from the left:

```
>>> arr1 = np.zeros([50,6,10])   # Swapped ("rolled") dimensions
>>> arr2 = np.zeros([6,10])
>>> arr1[25:26, :, :] = arr2     # No need to add an extra axis
```

It's just that it doesn't work when used from the right, as in your code.

Comment: What about using `arr2[..., None]` instead of `arr2.reshape(arr2.shape + (1,))` ?

Comment: @n `None` will indeed also work; I had just edited my answer before I saw your comment with that option, although I've used `np.newaxis` instead, to be more explicit. Trouble is, I feel there are too many options to solve this for a single, simple, consistent answer.

Comment: Thank you I finally used `arr1[:, :, range(25,26,1)] = arr2[..., None]`. because in my code the `range(25,26,1)` is a legacy variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `range(25, 26, 1)` is actually a single number, you could use either:

```
arr1[:, :, 25:26] = arr2[..., None]
```

or:

```
arr1[:, :, 25] = arr2
```

in place of `arr1[:, :, range(25,26,1)] = [arr2]`.

Note that for ranges/slices that do not reduce to a single number the first line would use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

The reason why your original code does not work is that you are mixing NumPy arrays and Python `list`s in a non-compatible way because NumPy interprets `[arr2]` as having shape `(1, 6, 10)` while the result expects a shape `(6, 10, 1)` (the error you are getting is substantially about that.)

---

The above solution targets at making sure that `arr2` is in a compatible shape.
Another possibility would have been to change the shape of the recipient, which would allow you to assign `[arr2]`, e.g.:

```
arr1 = np.zeros([50,6,10])
arr2 = np.zeros([6,10])
arr1[25:26, :, :] = [arr2]
```

This method may be less efficient though, since `arr2[..., None]` is just a memory view of the same data in `arr2`, while `[arr2]` is creating (read: allocating new memory for) a new `list` object, which would require some casting (happening under the hood) to be assigned to a NumPy array.